# Kusto / Azure Data Explorer - using ipv4_is_in_any_range to get WHICH range an IP is in

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have some IP address data in a column of one of my tables. I have a couple (about 250) watchlists of IP ranges with some metadata about each one. I want to connect each of the IP addresses from my column to the metadata in the list.

I cannot use a join as I would have to join on the condition ipv4_is_in_any_range(), and Kusto only supports join/lookup based on column equality.

I currently have the IP ranges as a list. I am able to extend the original IP address column using ipv4_is_in_any_range(), but I want to know WHICH range the IP address is in out of the list. How should I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
let IPrange_Metadata = datatable(Network:string, Metadata:string)[
     "192.168.1.0/24", "Local network 1",
     "10.0.0.0/8", "Local network 2",
     "172.16.0.0/12", "Local network 3"
];
let IPs = datatable(IP:string) [
    "10.1.2.3",
    "192.168.1.5",
    "172.16.11.21"
];
IPs
| extend dummy=1
| join kind = inner (IPrange_Metadata | extend dummy=1) on dummy
| where ipv4_is_in_range(IP, Network)
| project IP, Metadata
```

This query uses a join operation to match the IP addresses in the  `IPs`  table to the IP ranges in the  `IPrange_Metadata`  table. In this query,  `extend`  operator is used to add a new column called  `dummy`  to both tables, which is then used as the inner join key. Finally, `where`  operator is used to filter the joined table to only include rows where the IP address is within the IP range.

**Output:**

| IP | Metadata |
| --- | --- |
| 192.168.1.5 | Local network 1 |
| 10.1.2.3 | Local network 2 |
| 172.16.11.21 | Local network 3 |

[demo](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA2WQ0U7DMAxF3/sVVp5WqcrmbMAA9QMmAdo7QlVYrZGtc6Y0MJD4eJK0ZYwmD7Gujq9v3JCH1dpp3lL1SF7X2msoIT5evzY0eSJ/sm5/13pneFvAAPVC/pxBPAJvlcTrpUQ5m6qFKEA82I1ugLt+QFEM5EymO12OKXWmbqJf4lCNwbnIXu6zJqVvLwKv1kM06LLFgSiVnPfef6Je/UrdNAwcJufgmn0DfXriGur3w+GrxCDsrGHYm6CVYJjJwWS0vf9tOVju6mBweiNHYI4fi8q0leEqNQeTAvpN54E6OrujTfzbeeE/X5YlEqoBAAA=)

Comment: I've seen this method of using a cross-join, but I have too much data to do this (billions of records). Kusto runs out of memory

Comment: Thanks, this was the only solution I found this far!